# What are the ways to track inactivity with adobe dtm?

Tags: adobe-analytics

I'm new to Adobe DTM, after checking all Adobe DTM events it doesn't have a method to check for inactivity. Have anyone done this? How to do this? Thanks.

Comment: what does "inactivity" mean to you?

Comment: @CrayonViolent Very good question! The page is a  single page application, and there is no button. As soon user changes a number in any input field, it calculates results. So I want to wait for user to enter all information and capture the data and send it to dtm, so I would wait after a period of 15 seconds if there is no key pressed.

Comment: okay so there's no built-in way to do that in DTM but you can write your own code easy enough and put it into a page load rule with no conditions as 3rd party javascript.

Comment: Thank you, that's all I wanna know.

Comment: I had nothing better to do, here's a PoC of code itself: https://jsfiddle.net/qm3dm20e/

Comment: so as far as DTM is concerned, basically where the `alert()` is, you could call a direct call rule e.g. `_satellite.track('foobar')` and then setup a direct call rule with condition string "foobar" and pop all your stuff there

Comment: Perfect! I got it to work just like what you described. Create a PageLoad to load the javascript, and create a direct call rule for _satellite.track('rulename'). That's exactly what I need. Thanks so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I'm gonna answer my question based on the help from @CrayonViolent.

1. Create a `Page Load Rule` 
   Under `Conditions`, Trigger rule at `Bottom of Page`, it provides ample time for the page to load the elements before it runs the rule

   Under `Javascript / Third Party Tags`, I added my javascript to detect whether the input field value has changed, if it does, delays for 15 seconds then run `_satellite.setVar('blahblah', 'toSomething')` which allows me to use in the next step. Final step is `_satellite.track('mydirectcallname')`, to trigger the `Direct Call Rule`
2. Create a `Direct Call Rule` 
   Under `Conditions`, make sure `String` has the same value as in `_satellite.track('mydirectcallname')` (i.e. mydirectcallname) 
   Under `Adobe Analytics`, I set one of the eVar to use %blahblah%, which I defined in step 1.